# Why trivial quandle is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

A quandle is a set $X$ with a binary operation $*$ defined on $X$ and satisfying three axioms. The quandle where $x*y=x$ for any $x,y \in X$ is called a trivial quandle. I wonder why is it called trivial? I wonder if this has a relation with cocycle invariant defined for knots?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon may help ? as might https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles#Quandles

Comment: Are qunadle, quandle and qaundle different things?

Comment: I would think that it is called trivial because it doesn't do anything interesting at all.  There is a set, and the operation between two elements $(x,y)$ just always give $x$, *trivially*.  No calculation required.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial quandle for a non-empty $X$ is the one-element set $X=\{s\}$, defined by $s\triangleright s=s$.  In general, a trivial quandle decomposes as a disjoint union of these one-element quandles.

Every quandle $S$ has a quandle map to a trivial quandle $X$ defined by sending everything in $S$ to a single point in $X$.  This is like how every group has a homomorphism to the trivial group.

For knots, a quandle map from the knot quandle to the trivial quandle corresponds to a trivial coloring of the knot.  Looking for a non-trivial coloring of a knot by some quandle amounts to saying the image in the quandle is not a trivial quandle.